# Cooperative running of Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, windows-8

I have Windows 8.1 running on my laptop (i7, 16 GB RAM) and I am thinking about migrating to Ubuntu 14.04. However, I will still need Windows for years or even for ever as Windows is the working environment at my work and for most of my professional software (hydrology, GIS). What I would prefer is having both OS installed in dual boot. However, in daily use dual boot is not practical, as this needs regular switching between the two OS. In daily use I want to work with Ubuntu as my 'primary' OS, running Windows in a Virtualbox.

Now my question is: is it possible to run the existing (and still separately accessible) Windows in a VirtualBox and if so, how to configure this?

Note: @Rinzwind (see below) is right stating that my posting in a strict sense is not OS but VM related. However, in general my question is about how to enter de 'Linux world', at the same time being capable working under Windows inside Ubuntu. I am looking for useful suggestions.
Despite the promising environment of Ubuntu, in number of users it is still far behind Windows and Mac OS. I think there are many people like me, who want to make a (gradual) change to Linux, but are tight to Windows in some way due to their work and/or profession. I think Ubuntu would attract more users if it could cooperate with Windows in a proper and flexible way and if clear support and instructions of how to reach that would be available.

Comment: Seems off topic to me (you are asking about how to get a Windows instance into a VM; So it has no relation to the OS you are using to make the VM). Food for your mind: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows Link has also a list of problems someone faced doing this with XP and W7. Also: http://superuser.com/questions/484927/virtualbox-from-an-existing-partition Some say you can; most claim you can not.

Comment: I disagree that this is off-topic. This is a valid question with a clear usecase. It might already be answered on the site, though.

Answer (score 1):

I run both dual-boot and VirtualBox VMs. So far as Windows 8 in a VM all I recall needing to do is specify either Windows 7 or Other Windows as the machine type when I set up the machine, and then I connected the .iso file from my Microsoft Volume license download to the CD drive. For resources I use 1-2 CPUs, 2G RAM, 25G HD. I had no problem.

I have done this in VMWare and then VirtualBox with XP, Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, and now with the Windows 10 technical preview. The only problems have been Windows Server Essentials and Windows 10, which I had to work with substantially to get them to run even the install. If I recall correctly the key was telling VirtualBox to use Other Windows as the type. I also posted a YouTube video of the Windows 10 install, wherein you can see the VM setup on the first slide -- look for http://youtu.be/9EvPsa3YdAk This is extremely similar to Windows 8.1.

HOWEVER, I also dual boot, because in some cases I simply cannot get the VM install of Windows to work well enough. For office software this is not a problem, but for  gaming I have had no success using a VM, so I dual boot just for those few cases. This will also let you use Windows as you are learning the ropes in Linux when you simply need to get something done and can't figure out how to make Linux do it.

Now here is the key -- you must install the Windows FIRST, configure it, wait on all the updates, etc. then install the Linux. I do this every year on the 9 computers in my lab at Adult Life Training, and on my home desktop. I have never found a good way to install Microsoft after Linux is already installed, and also if you install the Microsoft first and let it do as much updating as possible before you install Linux, then you need not mess with the GRUB boot screen during all the Windows reboots from updating. After the Windows is installed then install the Linux on the other half of your drive.

I hope this helps! If I can help further please feel free to email kubulai0@gmail.com or post here.

Answer (score 0):

Hints with conversion instructions here:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows

and here:

https://superuser.com/questions/721981/how-do-i-migrate-my-windows-desktop-to-a-virtualbox-vm

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=51203

Virtualbox is a good choice. You will get:

- snapshots. It's nice to rollback guest machine, just in case of problems.
- easy access to files, saved in Linux, if Virtualbox addons are installed.
- direct USB/USB2 port access, needs Virtualbox extensions.
- NAT/Bridged (direct) network access.

Ask for help, if you are stuck on migration.